# How to control tube thickness

Tags: bevel

I have several tube as seen in the below image. A orange color circle seen that is the bevel circle made to the tube. Tube thickness is bigger than the orange circle. I do not want to affect the tube thickness as its present in the gray color. With the same tube thickness i want to have similar all tube size in the bevel i have given. How can i decrease the orange circle and match with the original tube thickness. Any suggestion or help Thanks
[image]

[image]

**Difference in tube thickness to 2 different circles** I have just duplicate the circle and scale. I get 2 result as seen in the gif file.
[image]

Comment: Why can't you can bevel all tubes with the same circle...?

Comment: @m.ardito yeah i have bevel with the same circle but the circle is big and the thickness is small of the tube. How can i control the circle and the thickness. If i lower the circle the tube thickness will shrink down

Comment: I added an answer to show images and test .blend.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two beziers pairs beveled to two differently sized circles: in my test, it's pretty much the same size... it could be something else, or I don't understand what you did.

[image]

my test .blend

[image]

Comment: I clear what i have did. With the curve circle i have added the shrinkwrap modifier then applied and converted to mesh and then again converted to curve and added the shrinkwrap modifier and then bevel.

Comment: i have added the blend file and 1 gif file

Answer (score 0):

Select the torus. Make sure it's not affected by the bezier and no modifiers. Go into edit-mode. Hold 'Alt' and start selecting all the rings that form the tube with edge select. [image]

Now, next to the drop down menu where you can switch between wire frame, solid, render etc. change the pivot point to 'individual origins'. Now you can scale it in thickness. But only in edit-mode.